# numpy fill matrix diagonal value with another matrix

Tags: python, numpy

Is that an easier way to fill a matrix diagonal element by another whole matrix?

```
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a = np.zeros((9, 9), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, b)
```

I expect the result will be

```
[[1. 0  0  ...........0 0]
 [0. 2. 0  ...........0 0]
 [0. 0. 3. ...  0  0  0 0]
 [0. 0. 0. 4 0  0  0  0 0]
 [0. 0. 0. 0 5  0  0  0 0]
 [0. 0. 0. ...  6  0  0 0]
 [0. 0. 0. ...  0  7  0 0]
 [0. 0. 0. ...  0  0  8 0]
 [0. 0. 0. ...  0  0  0 9]]
```

Comment: Is `b` always 1D?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method does work:

```
import numpy as np

b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
a = np.zeros((9, 9), int)

np.fill_diagonal(a, b)
```

An alternative:

```
a[np.diag_indices_from(a)] = b
```

Comment: `np.diag_indices(9)` will also work. Might be slightly faster (not that it's slow or anything though).

Comment: @busybear It's to be flexible and dynamic with the (possibly different) size of `a`. The performance difference is probably minuscule even if there is a difference.

Comment: Not really arguing either is better; they are essentially the same. `np.diag_indices` also has a second argument to set the dimensions. Although I do like that it's less characters to type :D

Answer (score 1):

Check

```
a[[np.arange(len(b))]*2]=b
a
Out[163]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```

Comment: Found a couple more ways here!

Comment: @coldspeed nice dude ~ :-)

Comment: @Wen-Ben: Your suggestion `a[[np.arange(len(b))]*2]` gives me a deprecation warning - "Using a non-tuple sequence for multidimensional indexing is deprecated". One way to avoid the warning is `a[(np.arange(len(b)), np.arange(len(b)))]=b`, or even simpler - `a[(range(len(b)), range(len(b)))]=b`

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the things `numpy.diag` does:

```
a = numpy.diag(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, `np.eye` with broadcasting.

```
np.eye(a.shape[0], dtype=int) * b

array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```

---

You can also use `diagflat`, if `b`'s dimensions are > 1D

```
np.diagflat(b)
# np.diagflat([b])
# np.diagflat(np.array([b]))

array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9]])
```